# Merging 2 rows and and adding values of matching reference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to merge two rows that have the same staff code but different posted hours and then add the hours.

Right now I get the following result:

```
STAFFCODE EXPTOTAL
------------------  
CON       6  
CON       8  
AEA       4  
ECC       3  
ECC       2
```

What I want to see is the following:

```
STAFFCODE EXPTOTAL
------------------  
CON       14   
AEA       4  
ECC       5
```

I have the results in a comma form as they need to be updated that way
`StaffCode,Exptotal`  so my results should look like this:

```
CON, 14  
AEA, 4  
ECC, 5
```

My code thus far is as follows:

```
select staffreference + ',' + '3' + ',' + 'MSC' + ',' + 
  convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,2),exptotal)) + ',' + ','  
from tblstaff s
inner join tblExpenseHeader h on h.ExpStaff = s.StaffIndex
where ExpApprovedOn> 'aug 25 2015'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the staff reference, and sum the exptotal. Modifying your original query, please try the following.

```
select staffreference + ',' + cast(sum(exptotal) as nvarchar(max))
from tblstaff s
inner join tblExpenseHeader h on h.ExpStaff = s.StaffIndex
where ExpApprovedOn > 'aug 25 2015'
group by staffreference
```

Comment: duh....haha how could I be this slow...i did the harder part haha I was getting so complicated with it hahahha I tried sum before but I was putting it in front of the convert